# checkboxes selected event and submit button

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have just finished small project on multiple checkboxes using ajax. The demo can be found here:[demo](http://hibbard.eu/blog/pages/phones_new/) . But now i want to use submit button for filter option. So now after multiple checkboxes are selected and after sumbit button are clicked then only it should change in the phone database. Any help ? Thanks. Here is my code:
Index.php

```
<body> 
    <h1>Phones database</h1>

    <table id="phones">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Brand</th>
          <th>Model</th>
          <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <div id="filter">
      <h2>Filter options</h2>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="Samsung" checked>
        <label for="Samsung">Samsung</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="iPhone" checked>
        <label for="iPhone">iPhone</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="HTC" checked>
        <label for="HTC">HTC</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="LG" checked>
        <label for="LG">LG</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="Nokia" checked>
        <label for="Nokia">Nokia</label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
    <script>
      function makeTable(data){
        console.log(data);
       var tbl_body = "";
          $.each(data, function() {
            var tbl_row = "";
            $.each(this, function(k , v) {
              tbl_row += "<td>"+v+"</td>";
            })
            tbl_body += "<tr>"+tbl_row+"</tr>";
          })

        return tbl_body;
      }

      function getPhoneFilterOptions(){
        var opts = [];
        $checkboxes.each(function(){
          if(this.checked){
            opts.push(this.id);
          }
        });

        return opts;
      }

      function updatePhones(opts){
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "submit.php",
          dataType : 'json',
          cache: false,
          data: {filterOpts: opts},
          success: function(records){
            $('#phones tbody').html(makeTable(records));
          }
        });
      }

      var $checkboxes = $("input:checkbox");
      $checkboxes.on("change", function(){
        var opts = getPhoneFilterOptions();
        updatePhones(opts);
      });

      $checkboxes.trigger("change");
    </script> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

submit.php

```
<?php 
require 'Database.php';
#### TEMP SET NAMES FÜR UTF8 ###################################################
include 'Json.php';
  $opts = $_POST['filterOpts'];
  $tmp = array();
  foreach ($opts as $opt) {
        $tmp[] = '"'.$opt.'"';
  }
        $query = 
      'SELECT mobile_phone.id, name, model, price FROM mobile_phone INNER JOIN brand ON brand_id = brand.id WHERE name IN ('.implode(",", $tmp).')';


  $result = mysql_query($query);
  $data   = array();
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $data[] = $row;
  }

echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: That's a nasty SQL injection hole you have there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line  `data: {filterOpts: opts},` change to

```
data: {filterOpts: $(':checked').val('id')}
```

this should pass ids of models.